# Rails 3 not using rvm?

Tags: 12.04, rails, rvm

I there any way to install this *** not using rvm? 
I've got rails 3.2.3 gem installed but terminal can't found binary.

If You tell me to use rvm - please show me some WORKING (step by step) tutorial!

Sorry, for my anger but i spend week trying to set it fast and easy as it was on rails 2, but i found lots of not working tutorials with rvm.

Comment: Weeks? Next time ask here first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install the ruby1.9.1-dev package (which, confusingly, is ruby 1.9.3.. ) then

```
gem1.9.1 install rails
```

As root, then rails will be fully built and installed as /usr/local/bin/rails

```
$ rails --version
Rails 3.2.3
```